# How to get visitor log (customer) collection

Tags: collection

I'm looking to load the `log/customer` collection and am running into some issues.

When using `Mage::getModel('log/customer')->load(1);` the appropriate data is returned but if I try to load the collection, it just returns `false`.

Here is what was tried:

```
Mage::getModel('log/customer')->getCollection(); //returns false
Mage::getResourceModel('log/customer_collection'); //returns false
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Mage_Log` is  the module whih stores log details in Magento. It mainly logs following details

```
Customers who logged in 

Past Vistors

Vistors who currently active

Quotes etc.
```

If you dig more deeply, you can see that, you can get `log-visitor` collection. However `log-customer` collection is not available. It is logical since, most of the time, you will only query about logs of a specific customer, not of multiple customers at a time. I think this is why core team of magento didn't include collection for `log-customer`s.

### To Get Collection Of Customers

Now take a look on the `Mage_Log` module's model section. You can see the entity `visitor` only holds the collection. But through this collection we can access `log-customer` collection!. What ? I can get log-collection through visitors ? Yes. Because let us have a look on `log_customer` table.

```
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| log_id | `visitor_id` | customer_id | login_at            | logout_at           | store_id |
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|      1 |        105 |           2 | 2014-02-05 18:49:10 | 2014-02-05 13:19:10 |        4 |
|      2 |        105 |           2 | 2014-02-05 13:19:30 | NULL                |        4 |
|      3 |        113 |           3 | 2014-08-05 10:26:08 | NULL                |        1 |
|      4 |        325 |           3 | 2014-09-04 01:32:18 | NULL                |        1 |
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Did you see `visitor_id` that is used in the table. This means, every time a user visit, magento will generate a vistor_id for that user and store in the table `log_visitor`. When a registered user then login to his account using his credentials, `log_customer` table will get updated. So each time a customer visit, a unique `visitor_id` reference will be associated with that user. So due to this, using visitor collection , we can access `log-customer` collection.

For an exmaple a simple query is shown below.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('eq' => 1));
$collection->getSelect()
            ->join( 
                array('log_customer'=> $collection->getTable('log/customer')),
                'main_table.`visitor_id`= log_customer.`visitor_id`'
            );
foreach ($collection->getItems() as  $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

This collection filter will return every `log-customer` who are available for store id = 1. Is that what you need ? :)

### Wrap up

So in short, you don't need any collection defined for `log-customer` entity. It is intended to access details of one customer at a time. If you need collection, you can use visitor collection for that. That is the correct way to do that :)

Hope that make sense

Comment: great answer, this code throws an error `Item (Mage_Log_Model_Visitor) with the same id "xxx" already exist` any suggestions

Comment: that is because you have more than one entry with same visitor_id in `log_customer`. The code works only when all visitor_id in `log_customer` table is unique

Comment: hmmm, does that mean that this code will crash on production...in other words is there a way i can avoid duplicates from appearing, or am i looking at this wrong

Comment: no dont use this code in production environment directly. I just show an example code. My point is, you can use `log-visitor` to get collection of a customer. It is your job to do a good coding based on this point. :). I just want to answer your question and my answer fulfills what the question demands

Comment: lol spoken like a true coder ;) thanks again

Comment: what can i do to get distinct on a join

Comment: lol. You know what this is the first time, I use getSelect() and join() in my code. So I dont think I can say whether that code is good. This is good code, if you modify little bit. Means you need to avoid duplicate entries. Actually I dont know how to do that. If you find it how can we do that, please inform me

Comment: he he ... that is what I am thinking about now :)

Comment: but good question. It teached me a lot. that is why +1 for this question

Answer (score 3):

This is because if you see the log Module in Magento there is no collection class for the customer model. There is no collection defined for you to instantiate.

Comment: true, what can be done to create one without changing the core

Answer (score 1):

overwrite class Mage_Log_Model_Customer resource class of log

using

```
 <models>
  <youmodulemodellnname>
  <class>yourModuleNmaeSapce_Modulename_Modelname</class>
  </youmodulemodellnname>
     <log_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <customer_collection>yourModuleNmaeSapce_Modulename_Modelname_Resource_Custome_Collectionr</customer_collection>
        </rewrite>
    </log_resource>
  </log>
</models>
```

now create a collection file
code is

```
<?php
class yourModuleNmaeSapce_Modulename_Modelname_Resource_Custome_Collectionr
extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _constuct(){
        $this->_init('log/customer'); 
    $this->_visitorTable        = $this->getTable('log/visitor');
    $this->_visitorInfoTable    = $this->getTable('log/visitor_info');
    $this->_urlTable            = $this->getTable('log/url_table');
    $this->_urlInfoTable        = $this->getTable('log/url_info_table');
    $this->_customerTable       = $this->getTable('log/customer');
    $this->_quoteTable          = $this->getTable('log/quote_table');

    }


  public function function addLoadSelect()
    {
        $select =$this->getSelect;


            $table  = $this->getMainTable();
            $select
                ->joinInner(
                    array('lvt' => $this->_visitorTable),
                    "lvt.visitor_id = {$table}.visitor_id",
                    array('last_visit_at'))
                ->joinInner(
                    array('lvit' => $this->_visitorInfoTable),
                    'lvt.visitor_id = lvit.visitor_id',
                    array('http_referer', 'remote_addr'))
                ->joinInner(
                    array('luit' => $this->_urlInfoTable),
                    'luit.url_id = lvt.last_url_id',
                    array('url'))
                ->order("{$table}.login_at DESC");

        return $select;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I dont think this will work, because the class you are are trying to rewrite... actually doesn't exist !

Comment: thanks for the idea, tried a variant of this, looking though for a cleaner solution

Comment: that why programmer_rkt i have rewrite class  and as i  am not  inherent it parent class on rewrite class so it not creating  any issue