# How to Get Distinct Entries from Joined Tables Through Join()

Tags: collection, log, join, join-table

This doubt aroused when I am answering one of the [question that posted here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34784/how-to-get-visitor-log-customer-collection/). But this question is not a continuation of that question, rather a general doubt.

Basically I need to get `log-customer` collection. I can't get it directly, since there is no collection defined for log customers. ie

```
Mage::getModel('log/customer')->getCollection(); //false
```

However I can get the above collection indirect way. I need to use `log-visitor` collection for this and then using this collection I can get `log-customer` collection. This is the code that do that trick.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('eq' => 1));
$collection->getSelect()
            ->join( 
                array('log_customer'=> $collection->getTable('log/customer')),
                'main_table.`visitor_id`= log_customer.`visitor_id`'
            );
foreach ($collection->getItems() as  $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

This code will do the trick if everything came right. But there is a small problem related to this code. In order to show what is the problem, let me show you `log_customer` table.

```
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| log_id | `visitor_id` | customer_id | login_at            | logout_at           | store_id |
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|      1 |        105 |           2 | 2014-02-05 18:49:10 | 2014-02-05 13:19:10 |        4 |
|      2 |        105 |           2 | 2014-02-05 13:19:30 | NULL                |        4 |
|      3 |        113 |           3 | 2014-08-05 10:26:08 | NULL                |        1 |
|      4 |        325 |           3 | 2014-09-04 01:32:18 | NULL                |        1 |
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Here you can see that, there are multiple entries for `visitor_id` = 105. That duplicate entry came because, customer didn't logout properly. (See `null` value of second duplicate entry). Hence if I filter `log-customer` collection for `store_id` = 4. It will throw an error, which seems like this.(the code will work as expected store_id = 1, since there is no duplicate entries)

> ( ! )Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Item
>   (Mage_Log_Model_Visitor) with the same id "105" already exist' in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento_v1.8\lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php on line 373
>
> ( ! ) Exception: Item (Mage_Log_Model_Visitor) with the same id "105"
>   already exist in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento_v1.8\lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php on line 373

So in general, I need to avoid this. So ***how can I distinct my join query*** ***?*** Please enlighten me with your beautiful thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: you could always make your own collection class....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could consider doing is adding a `group by` clause for the visitor_id column.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('eq' => 1));
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
        array('log_customer'=> $collection->getTable('log/customer')),
        'main_table.`visitor_id`= log_customer.`visitor_id`'
    )->group('main_table.visitor_id');
```

But you might also need to add an order by to make sure that you get the newest results first.

Comment: Can you add any example how can I get newest results first? Tried `->order('log_customer.visitor_id')`, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

```
Zend_Db_Select::distinct()
```

The above method should help you. You could just call it by:

```
$collection->getSelect()->distinct();
```

Comment: I have tried getCollection->distinct(true); didn't work. I will try your code now

Comment: where should I put `join()` ? before or after `distinct()` ?

Comment: The distinct method is present in the Zend_Db_Select class and not in the collection class heirarchy. Calling getSelect() on the collection returns you the object to Varien_Db_Select class that inherits from the zend class.

Comment: You can put distinct wherever. The query is formed and executed only at the time collection->load() is called.The order shouldn't matter.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I have tried `distinct()`, `distinct(true)`.

Comment: After you are adding distinct and just before you load the collection do this:

print_r((string)$collection->getSelect())

This will show you the select query being fired. Check that.

Comment: yep but please note I am not loading collection. I am doing it an indirect way. That is using `getItems()` :)

Comment: Yeah get items would do a load as well. Just log it before you call getItems.

Comment: ``SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.*, `log_customer`.* FROM `log_visitor` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `log_customer` ON main_table.`visitor_id`= log_customer.`visitor_id` WHERE (main_table.store_id = 1)`` this is the query that generating. As I guess, `distinct` is applying for `log_visitor`. I think it will work if `distinct` get applied to `log_customer`. But unfortunately it is not possible, since I cant use `log_customer` collection instead of `log_visitor` link. Please refer the link that I provided in the question

Comment: +1 for the answer, since in normal case it should work. Hower my problem still persists. So I can't accept the answer right now. :)

Comment: Add attribute to select as only visitor_id for main table. So the select becomes: Select Distinct main_table.visitor_id...try it...

Answer (score 2):

Distinct and Group, as described by David and Paras, will work on 9 out of 10 queries. If it doesn't, make sure that you aren't reusing the column name of the primary column of the collection.

The following does not work all the time because catalog_product_entity has a column named entity_id which is the primary column of the order collection

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->getCollection();

    $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId)
    ;

    $order_collection->getSelect()
        ->join($sales_order_item_table,
            "$sales_order_item_table.order_id = main_table.entity_id")
        ->join(new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$product_collection->getSelect().')'),
            "t.entity_id = $sales_order_item_table.product_id")
        ->group("main_table.entity_id")
    ;
```

To fix it, just add an empty array as the third parameter of the join

```
        $order_collection->getSelect()
        ->join($sales_order_item_table,
            "$sales_order_item_table.order_id = main_table.entity_id",
            array())
        ->join(new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$product_collection->getSelect().')'),
            "t.entity_id = $sales_order_item_table.product_id",
            array())
        ->group("main_table.entity_id")
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding the join make sure blank array is passed in the third parameter.

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    'sales_order_item',
    'sales_order_item.order_id = main_table.order_id',
    []
);
```

After that add following to apply DISTINCT

```
$this->getSelect()->distinct(true);
```